# Can't get Content of the folder using Skydrive API

Tags: javascript, api, onedrive

I have real problem in displaying the content of the folders which are located inside the root directory. It managed to determine the folders which are in the Files directory but when I try to do the same to one of those folders It doesn't work.

I delieve the problem in the path name of a WL.api. However I may be mistaken.

I used code samples from skydrive page of live connect development center. in the sample below I tried to determine folders first, but eventually I would like to get the names  of all files stored in a particular directory.

```
 WL.api({ path: "me/skydrive/files/myfolder", method: "get" }).then(
  function (response) {
   var items = response.data;
   var outPuts = "";
   var number = items.length
    var tempos = new Array();
   var foundFolder = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].type === "folder" || items[i].type === "album") {
    tempos[i] = items[i].name;
    foundFolder += 1;
  }
  }
     if (foundFolder == 0) {
        folderss.innerHTML = ("Unable to find any folders");
     }
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        outPuts = outPuts + tempos[i] + "<br /> <br />"
       }
     folderss.innerHTML = outPuts;
    }
 }
 );
```

if I retain only **"me/skydrive/files"** for WL path. it works. But if I add any particular folder name afer it like in my case **"me/skydrive/files/myfolder"** the call returns nothing. or may be I shall declare a path like: **"me/skydrive/files/folder.567391047.34282821!"**

Thank you for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is due to the fact that you are using an invalid path format. According to [the examples from the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#objectdata), a valid path to list files has the following form: **/OBJECT_ID/files**, where OBJECT_ID may be replaced by **me/skydrive** to reference the Skydrive root folder.

The important things to note are that:

1. there can be a reference (**OBJECT_ID**) to only one object;
2. this reference can only be the ID of an object (as returned by the API) or a special alias such as **me/skydrive**;
3. **/files** should always be the last part of the path (assuming we do not need to use a query string).

Thus, to list the contents of your subfolder **folder.567391047.34282821!**, you should try using the following path format instead:
**/folder.567391047.34282821!/files** or even **folder.567391047.34282821!/files** (without the leading slash, as it seems to be optional).

Please let me know if this solves your issue.